# Xamarin custom attribute of reference type does not work

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to create a custom attribute for my control.  Here's my attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="ImageView">
    <attr name="testcustom" format="reference"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In my test app at root, I add this namespace xmlns:TestCustom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Later in my layout file I have an image view

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/Icon"
    TestCustom:testcustom="@drawable/Icon"/>
```

The first android:src property is fine, however TestCustom does not work.

The error given is "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'testcustom' with value '@drawable/icon)

So... what's going on here?  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you specified xmlns:TestCustom ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your `xmlns:` to your specific package namespace. For example:

`xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews"`

Represents `custom:` for the package namespace of `com.example.customviews`.

You can read more about this here: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr

**Note: You may want to consider following the convention of `camelCase` with regards to your custom attributes, views, etc.**

Comment: Actually, I've tried this already, and it didn't work for me...  I think I'm on to something now though because for some reason when I lowercased my @drawable it started to compile???  Not sure what's going on here, going to investigate more and report back.

Comment: Yes, because `aapt.exe` does not like things with capitalization / hyphens / etc. I would advise you to use `camelCase` and/or underscores for these items.

Answer (score 0):

So to recap:  The solution here was to use lower case name when referencing the resource via a custom attribute.  Apparently Xamarin is doing some work in the background that normally allows resources that start with upper case to be OK, but it probably doesn't address this for custom attributes.

If you are using Xamarin, and custom attributes and you can't reference your resource, try it in lower case!!!

Or as Jon recommends, don't use upper-case stuff at all for resources.